# How to add a counters total into this array

Tags: c#, arrays

I almost figured this out, except I don't know how to put the actual result of the counter into the array instead of just the counter name. Then, I want it to loop and increase the `Price` by `1` for each increase the counter has (For example if `Counter285` was `7` `Price285` would be incremented by `7` by the end of the loop). It's late and this might be obvious. Sorry.

```
double[] arr = new double [] {Counter285, Counter134, Counter085};        
foreach (double i in arr)
{
    if (i == Counter285)
        Price285++;
    else if (i == Counter134)
        Price134++;
    else
        Price085++;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I was not able to understand your question. May you please describe what do you want to exactly do? :)

Comment: Counter285, Counter134, Counter085 all count up 1 each time a button is clicked. This code is for the second button. I want the totals of these counts in the array. Currently I just have the "Name" of the counter. Then I want the foreach loop to increase Price285,Price134,Price085 by one for each amount each counter has. (For example if Counter 285 had 7 counts, it would increase Price285 by 7). I know this might seem overly complicated for what I want to achieve but I want to use an array to achieve it

Comment: Thanks for providing the information I think that I got you now. I'll try my best! :)

Comment: I'm glad you were able to find an answer to your question. Have a great day! :)

Comment: This is highly confusing. It seems the counters are integers, so why is your array of doubles? And why are you using an Array in the first place?

Comment: For that matter, what is your question exactly? Your code is "doing" something, but it's far from obvious what is wrong with it, because it's not clear at all what you would like it to do.

Comment: Your variable names can be improved. A variable name should reflect what it's for. "StockPrice", for example, is much clearer than "Price#". "MegacomglomacorpStockPrice" is even more clear, and can't really be compressed. "megaconglomacorp.StockPrice" is even better.

Comment: @NarftheMouse I agree with you, and I think that every programmer have his own preferences in specifying variable names. I, for example, would use the following variable name if I would like to indicate that it is used for a price `P`. Every programmer have his own rights in choosing the variable names based on what is suitable for him. Perhaps `P` would be confusing to most of people, but for me, it's really comfortable. Please also note that periods are not allowed for variable names as well. Have a great day :)

Comment: A variable named "P" fails the most important check - Readability. You can make bad variable names all you want in your own code. Trust me, you'll hate yourself for it later. Also, other people have to read your code if you do anything professional. They have a right to readable code. A book for you: "Code Complete". Read it, learn it, use it. "I do it this way" has nothing to do with correct code. Lastly, "megaonglomacorp.StockPrice" is a perfectly valid variable name, where ".StockPrice" is a member of class or struct variable "megaconglomocorp".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I've understood from your last comment, you'd like to increment `Price285` by the value of `Counter285`

> For example if Counter 285 had 7 counts, it would increase Price285 by 7

I think this is very simple, just replace `Price285++;` with `Price285 += Counter285;`

**Example**

```
int Counter285= 0, Counter134 = 0, Counter085 = 0;
int Price285= 0, Price134 = 0, Price085 = 0;
double[] arr = new double[] { Counter285, Counter134, Counter085 };

foreach (double i in arr)
{
    if (i == Counter285)
    {
        Price285 += Counter285;
    }
    else if (i == Counter134)
    {
        Price134 += Counter134;
    }
    else
    {
        Price085 += Counter085;
    }
}
```

Thank you,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: Thank you it works. I also changed Price134 and Price085 to similar

Comment: @Rob Glad I could help. I have edited my answer based on your comment. Have a great day! :)

Comment: While this might work, something about the overall approach is really smelly. The array seems useless, you might as well remove the foreach and directly update the variables

Comment: @Mathias Why do you think the array is useless? It can be then used later to sort the doubles in this array. Thank you anyways :)

Comment: My point still holds. An array is intended to be used by index, you should operate on its contents in a generic manner. You could update the variables and then return them as an array, with much less code.

Comment: @Mathias Perhaps you are right, Array has also got many other functions beside indexing which can be used in the future. Have a great day :)

Comment: Different angle on my negative reaction: the point of using a collection is to handle generically items of same nature. Yet in this case, every time I would add a "counter", I would need to add an if statement. The dictionary angle sounds much more correct here, or maybe a list of items with their click count.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, your answer works. What I question is the design taken in the question, which seems really flawed.

Comment: @Mathias I agree with you! The Dictionary seems more creative but less simpler! Rob had no acknowledgement how to use a Dictionary as commented below. Every programmer have his own preferences and creativity as long as the output is still the same. For me, I'll try to be simple as possible while programming so that many others can understand how was my application written when they see the Project code. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
Dictionary<String, int> CountTable = new Dictionary<string, int>();

CountTable.Add("Counter285", 7);
CountTable.Add("Counter134", 8);
CountTable.Add("Counter085", 9);

int Count = CountTable["Counter085"];
```

Comment: Sorry Im too new at c# to fully understand this but thank you for helping :)

Comment: @Rob `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is a Generic Collection that is just like `Array` but it gives you the opportunity to add TWO values. Then, it allows you to get the value later using the `TKey`. For example, from the above code posted by [Steve Wellens](http://stackoverflow.com/users/479869/steve-wellens), There's a dictionary `CountTable` made possible by a `TKey: String` and `TValue: int`. Steve used `CountTable.Add();` to add a new item to the dictionary. As the item consists of TWO keys, Steve used `CountTable.Add("Counter285", 7);` to add the key name "Counter085" and its value `9`...

Comment: @Rob Then, Steve was able to get the value of the key by `int Count = CountTable["Counter085"];`. Steve used `int Count` as `CountTable["Counter085"]` will return an `int` based on its value.

Comment: @Rob There's also another Generic Collection `List<T>` (where T represents an element) but it does not allow you to look up the value of a Key. It will only allow you to Add or Remove objects. For example, you can use `List<string> MyC = new List<string();` to create a new collection of `List<T>`. Then, you may call `MyC.Add("Item");` to add an item with the name "Item" to  `MyC`. The default Key for `List<T>` is `int` (Index)...

Comment: @Rob So that if you added `MyC.Add("Item");` it will be assigned with a special index starting from 0 which can be then used to detect an item within a `List<T>`. For example, using `MessageBox.Show(MyC[MyC.IndexOf("Item")]);` will return "Item".

Comment: And the assumption I made was that you have counters with names that each have different increment values (Counter085 increments by 9).